# What does the code "local a = (...);" in a required script mean?

Tags: module, lua, require

In a Lua file, I got the following code:

```
local mod_name = (...);
```

I have tried the code `print(mod_name)`, and I got the file name `"pb"`.
The whole script is called from another script by `require('pb');`.
I knew the meaning of `(...)` in function for multiple arguments, but I'm confused with this.

Comment: And what does "module(...);" mean ?

Comment: BTW-semicolons in Lua are optional. (Where they separate identifiers and keywords, they could be replaced by whitespace.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main body of a script, `...` results in the arguments to the script. It has the same function as the `arg` table, see [Lua Standalone](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#7) reference manual.

```
for _, v in ipairs{...} do
    print(v)
end
```

For instance, if it's called with `test.lua arg1 arg2`, this would output:

```
arg1
arg2
```

Note that in your `local mod_name = (...)`, only the first element is kept because of the parenthesis.

---

In your example, the script is called from another script using `require('pb')`. And in this case, it's loaded with two arguments, the first is the module name `'pb'`, the second, is dependent on how `require` got the loader. For details, read the manual of [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-require).

Comment: But in my case, there is no arguments for the script, only "require('test');". so the "..." should be nil, right?

Comment: @RoyHu Why don't you show that in the question? [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

`...` represents a list of arguments, either to the chunk (e.g., script) or to a function declared as `function (named_arg_1, named_arg_2, ...)` or `function (...)`.

A list can be concatenated to a list, as in `{1, 2, ...}` or `print("args:",...)`. In these examples it is used in the context of a list. Otherwise, it expands only to the first value.

In `local a = (...)`, the context is not a list due to the parentheses forming the expression. So, it assigns `a` the first value.

The parentheses seem to be stylistic because although `local a = ...` has a list context, `a` is still assigned the first value. Other examples: `local a, b = ...` would assign the second value to `b` and `local a, b = (...)` would assign `nil` to `b`.

---

From this, it should be clear that `module(...)` calls the value held by module as a function with a list of parameters expanded from the `...` list.

Comment: Thanks! The script is called from "require('test');", no more arguments, how can "..." not be nil ?

Comment: Because `require` passes its argument to the loaded chunk. See [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require). Also note that later Lua versions add additional arguments, so it's a good idea to call the `module` function like this: `module( (...) )`, so that the additional arguments are not passed to `module` by accident.

Comment: Thank you!! I had tested that, and just before i found that i have got some error in my testing code. Thanks for you help!!